# Ajax github jobs call return CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github

I'm working with jobs.github API and trying to receive JSON from the API. I tried to set `dataType` to `JSONP` and get this error:

> MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I tried to set URL to cURL and I'm getting a HTML page where I called the function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=java&location=berlin',
  headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
  type: 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something with json
  },
  error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // error
  }
```

I'm getting CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in console. I think it's some fundamental error, where am I going wrong?

Comment: A raw json file is not going to implement `jsonp`

Comment: The error means that the receiving endpoint has not enabled requests from client-side logic hosted on third-party domains. You need to make the request server side instead.

Comment: So i lost like half day to do job with client side app, but it can't be done.